# Расчёт индекса доходности (DSI)

Tags: mysql, sql

Индекс расчитывается по формуле:

> **Index = (X + Y) / 14**

где, *Х* - количество  лет подряд из последних семи лет, в которые выплачивались дивиденды,
а *Y* - количество лет подряд из последних семи лет, в которые размер дивиденда был не ниже размера дивидендов предыдущего года.

Если дивидендеды выплачиваются 7 и более лет, то Х = 7, из этих 7 лет дивиденды только росли, то индекс будет равен 1 =  ( 7 + 7 ) / 14

*Структура таблицы*

```
create table dividends
(
    id            bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    company          varchar(5) not null,
    date             date         null,
    summ             integer      null
)
```

*данные*

```
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','19-12-20','192');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','19-07-09','155');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','18-12-21','95');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','18-07-11','130');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','17-12-22','85');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','17-07-10','120');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','16-12-23','75');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','16-07-12','112');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','15-12-24','65');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','15-07-14','94');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','14-12-26','60');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','14-07-15','60');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','13-08-15','50');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','13-01-13','50');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','12-11-12','40');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompA','12-01-11','75');
-----------------------------
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','19-01-11','75');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','18-01-11','25');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','17-01-11','75');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','16-01-11','60');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','15-01-11','55');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','14-01-11','45');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','13-01-11','35');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompB','12-01-11','25');
-----------------------------');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompC','19-02-21','75');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompC','18-03-12','70');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompC','14-06-01','40');
INSERT INTO dividends(`company`, `date`, `summ`) VALUES ('CompC','13-07-22','20');
```

Есть **таблица с данными**

```
Company | date        | summ
  CompA    2019-12-20    192
  CompA    2019-07-09    155
  CompA    2018-12-21    95
  CompA    2018-07-11    130
  CompA    2017-12-22    85
  CompA    2017-07-10    120
  CompA    2016-12-23    75
  CompA    2016-07-12    112
  CompA    2015-12-24    65
  CompA    2015-07-14    94
  CompA    2014-12-26    60 
  CompA    2014-07-15    60
  CompA    2013-08-15    50
  CompA    2013-01-13    50
  CompA    2012-11-12    40
  CompA    2012-01-11    75
-----------------------------
  CompB    2019-01-11    75
  CompB    2018-01-11    25
  CompB    2017-01-11    75
  CompB    2016-01-11    60
  CompB    2015-01-11    55
  CompB    2014-01-11    45
  CompB    2013-01-11    35
  CompB    2012-01-11    25
-----------------------------
  CompC    2019-02-21    75
  CompC    2018-03-12    70
  CompC    2014-06-01    40
  CompC    2013-07-22    20
```

В **результате** запроса должно получиться:

```
Company | dsi
  CompA  0.93
  CompB  0.57
  CompC  0.28
```

CompA - 0.93. В 2013 summ меньше чем в 2012, поэтому значения для формулы будут такими: X = 7, Y = 6.

CompB - 0.57. В 2018 summ меньше чем за предыдущий год, поэтому значения для формулы будут такими: X=7. Y=1. Отсчёт ведётся от последнего года ( максимального )

CompC - 0.28. Количество лет подряд = 2, поэтому значения для формулы будут такими: X=2. Y=2.

***Примечания***
***1.*** Все пограничные значения ( 1 января и 31 декабря ) считаются в тот год в который они записаны . Можно воспользоваться функцией `YEAR(date)`

***2.*** Сумма за год - это сумма всех дивидентов в течении года. Запрос для получения суммы за год может выглядеть так: `select company,sum(summ) from dividends group by company,YEAR(date)`

***3.*** Чтобы узнать был росли ли дивиденды в 7-й год, необходимо сравнить сумму с 8-м годом. Сейчас 2020, чтобы узнать росли ли дивиденды 7 лет назад ( в 2013 ), необходимо сравнить их с суммой дивидентов за 2012.

***4.*** Версия сервера:

```
select @@version;
-- 10.2.32-MariaD
```

***5.*** Для расчёта переменной

*Как в (my)sql сделать такой запрос?*

Comment: *Если размер дивиденда 7 лет назад меньше, чем 8 лет назад - это учитывается? или первый год по-любому считается "не меньше"?*

- Учитывается.

Comment: *Публикуя скрипты - следите за соответствием. Что за бардак в именах полей?* - Исправил

Comment: *CompB - 0.57. В 2018 summ меньше чем за предыдущий год, поэтому значения для формулы будут такими: X=7. Y=1. Отсчёт ведётся от последнего года ( максимального )* - так понятно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT company, 
                 YEAR(record_date) record_year, 
                 SUM(summ) summ
          FROM dividends
          GROUP BY 1, 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT company, 
                 record_year, 
                 summ, 
                 LAG(summ) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year) lag_summ, 
                 LAG(record_year) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year) lag_year,
                 (summ < COALESCE(LAG(summ) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year), 0)) summ_not_over,
                 (COALESCE(LEAD(record_year) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year), YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)) - record_year) != 1 is_not_consecutive
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT company, 
                 record_year, 
                 summ,
                 SUM(summ_not_over) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year DESC) summ_over,
                 SUM(is_not_consecutive) OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY record_year DESC) is_consecutive
          FROM cte2
          WHERE record_year >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 7 )
SELECT company, (SUM(!is_consecutive) + SUM(!(summ_over + is_consecutive))) / 14 DSI
FROM cte3
GROUP BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8a5045872c7999f22726ce0a778fff39)

Comment: Благодарю. Работает.
Осталось понять "магию" запроса. Можете пояснить?

Comment: fiddle дано. Смотрите, что за результат даёт `cte1`, поймите смысл каждого поля и каждого его возможного значения, потом то же с `cte2` и `cte3`. Логика-то несложная - просто аккуратности требует при написании. Вот так: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a85d2dbf87e4ab732bc672bacc6a9def